# Merging line features by location and attribute using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to merge only line features in my layer that touch each other and additional share a specific attribute.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dissolve` by attribute, then run `multi- to single-part`, then re-add relevant attributes which might have been lost during the dissolve.

Comment: great thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: one more question, i added a screenshot in the post. In the specific case, that I have an intersection with the same attributes and i use your approach it does not dissolve them together, is there a solution?

Comment: That seems to be a different question, and one, which cannot be solved without example data and/or your exact input to the GUI.

Comment: okay I added a example dataset, I want to dissolve by the attribute "durchmesse"

Comment: @Barrylim_work that is a quite different question. Please don't mix questions up or chain them, instead mark solutions and post follow-up question separately.